# Javascript create array from external data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that outputs the following code:

```
{"success":"true","query":[{"song_id":"1","song_name":"Prova 1","artist_id":"1","artist_name":"Banana Bomb","description":null,"status":"0","giftable":"1"},{"song_id":"2","song_name":"Prova 2","artist_id":"1","artist_name":"Banana Bomb","description":null,"status":"0","giftable":"1"}]}
```

Now, I call this page with a script and get its content, but how can I create an array in javascript by parsing this code?
Thanks.

Comment: did I understand it wrong or is it simple as data["query"]

Comment: your output is already an array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is JSON and can be converted to an array using jQuery

```
$.parseJSON(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'urlToData',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(res){
       console.log(res);
       console.log(res.success);
       console.log(res.query);
   }
});
```

OR

```
JSON.parse(stringWithData);
```